# build python opencv with ffmpeg support on Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, ffmpeg, buildpack

I am using this buildpacks to install ffmpeg on heroku

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg.git
```

and this buildpacks to install python opencv on heroku

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 3 https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy.git
```

I can use ffmpeg command and python opencv on heroku separately. Using python opencv, I can open and read image. However I cannot read video. Somehow opencv is not compiled with ffmpeg. My question is how can I compile python opencv with ffmpeg support.

Comment: Did you find the proper buildpack to read video on Heroku?

Comment: I use this tutorial to build it myself (http://scottlobdell.me/2014/10/install-opencv-heroku-ffmpeg-support/). This is my buildpack (https://bitbucket.org/nguyend1990/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv)

Comment: @KevinTan I tried your buildpack and the ome suggested in the tutorial as well and I'm getting the same error 'not supported ffmpeg version'.  Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe because the ffmpeg version is too old. You need to build it yourself with recent ffmpeg version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy` buildpack does not actually compile anything. It downloads already compiled environment and just plugs in into Heroku app.

But what you can do is to modify `https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy/blob/master/Dockerfile` to include ffmpeg. Then you can rebuild this container and change buildpack to download your modified version. It will require a lot of work, but I think that's the best option. Or you can find a another buildpack that will have all required libraries.